# Unhandled promise rejection [Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'LocationType'. It must be a valid React Component.]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So I am trying to convert a string to an enum type and use it as a type in useState:

From

```
const [someType, setSomeType] = useState<"water", "air", "fire">("water")
```

This works fine but when I try to convert this to an enum type like

```
export enum SomeType {
  WATER,
  AIR,
  FIRE,
}
  const [someType, setSomeType] = useState<SomeType>(SomeType.WATER)
```

this throws and error

`Unhandled promise rejection [Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'SomeType'. It must be a valid React Component.]`

I have tried other ways too like

```
const [someType, setSomeType] = useState<SomeType.WATER | SomeType.AIR | SomeType.FIRE>(SomeType.WATER)
```

But the error is the same, Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it myself so not sure if it'll work but you can try:

```
enum Example {}

...

const [type, setType] = useState({} as Example)
```